# passing arrays to functions in tcl. Only upvar?

Tags: tcl

As far as I understand, in tcl if you want to pass a named array to a function, you have to access the upper scope of the caller via the `upvar` command within the callee body. Is this the only way to pass an array in tcl ?

Answer (score 9):

As Michael indicated, there are several ways, plus a wiki page that discusses it. Just to have some of that information here, some options are:

**By Upvar**

```
proc by_upvar {&arrName} {
    upvar 1 ${&arrName} arr
    puts arr(mykey)
    set arr(myotherkey) 2
}
set myarr(mykey) 1
by_upvar myarr
info exists myarr(myotherkey) => true
```

- results in changes to the array being seen by the caller

**By array get/set**

```
proc by_getset {agv} {
    array set arr $agv
    puts arr(mykey)
    set arr(myotherkey) 2
    return [array get arr]
}
set myarr(mykey) 1
array set mynewarr [by_upvar myarr]
info exists myarr(myotherkey) => false
info exists mynewarr(myotherkey) => true
```

- results in changes to the array being seen by the caller
- similar mechanism can be used to return an array

Comment: What's up with the amperand in your by_upvar proc?  Not Tcl syntax.

Comment: @glenn jackman: "not tcl syntax"? Nonsense! Everything is tcl syntax :-). Since variable names can be any string and & is used in some other languages to signify the address of a variable, it makes a handy semi-quasi-self-documenting way of desgnating it as a target of an upvar. Funny how after all oh-so-many years I never thought to use &; I usually use _ or fooVar (upvar $fooVar foo).

Comment: OK, true.  I usually use "varname".  There is an error in the upvar command though:  should be `upvar 1 $&arrName arr`

Comment: Updated to account for the error (&a -> ${&a}). As Bryan, indicated, it's used merely as a self-documenting way of saying it's an upvar'd variable name. I can't take credit for it though, as I copied it from some other well known Tcler, though I can't recall from who.

Answer (score 5):

There are [other ways](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3262), like converting it into a list first (via `array get` and `array set`).

Answer (score 4):

If you're only passing in the *value* of the array, you could pass in a dictionary instead (hint: [`array get`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm#M8) serializes an array into a dictionary value) and use the [`dict`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.htm) command to access values in it. But if you want access to the live value, `upvar` is definitely easiest. It's also a very fast technique; it compiles down to an extra traversal of a pointer during variable access after `upvar` itself finishes.